# Sending an XML string inside a SOAP envelope

Tags: xml, web-services, soap

I am trying to call a third-party webservice that is looking for an an xml string inside the soap envelope. However, when I pass in an xml string, the server responds with 400 Bad Request. If I leave the xml out, then the webservice correctly returns an error stating that it is expecting that parameter. I've spoken to the devs for the webservice, and they're not sure why this is happening.

Here is the SOAP envelope I'm sending, the problematic node is `<web:xmlString>`.

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:web="http://webservices.example.com/">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <web:AddWidget>
         <web:Key>6F257576-2F95-4764-8539</web:Key>
         <web:listID>62017</web:listID>
         <web:Type>S</web:Type>
         <web:format>HTML</web:format>
         <web:xmlString><xml><Emails><Emailaddress>foo@bar.com</Emailaddress><User1>263885</User1></Emails></xml></web:xmlString>
         <web:sfID>1536</web:sfID>
      </web:AddWidget>
   </soapenv:Body>
```

I've tried putting the xml string in quotes, encoding it, etc without luck.

Comment: Impossible to answer without seeing the WSDL and XML Schema for the web service

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to do this.

```
<web:xmlString><xml><Emails><Emailaddress>foo@bar.com</Emailaddress><User1>263885</User1></Emails></xml></web:xmlString>
```

Not sure. You can either try that, or try without using an  tag pair.

```
<web:xmlString><Emails><Emailaddress>foo@bar.com</Emailaddress><User1>263885</User1></Emails></web:xmlString>
```

Either of the above should work.
Other wise you need to see the XSD if any, or the WSDL more properly.
HTH

Comment: -1: You can't have an XML document in the middle of a document.

Comment: Still doesn't help the OP, which is not surprising since he gave so little information.

Answer (score 0):

I know its old but  the following one also might help you or the late ones ;)
Better late than never.

You can send it as raw xml

```
<web:xmlString><xml><Emails><Emailaddress>foo@bar.com</Emailaddress><User1>263885</User1></Emails></xml></web:xmlString>
```

If you declare the xmlString as [XElement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xelement.aspx) data type